# Retrieve values at the time of edit  in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp. I have the list of names in the database. I need to get the list of names at the time of enter the values in the textbox  as like a google search(using Ajax).
I need the simple sample for this.Can anyone help me !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Follows:

In Javascript using Ajax:

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    url=url+"?val="+str1;

    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);

    xmlhttp.send(null);

    document.getElementById('my2').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Where `url` will be the URL to which you will post data. `Str1` is the typed value in textbox. and `my2` is the box which you will show as auto suggest.

At serverside coding in Servlet get the names from db and send it in response to display.